# Installing React in Meteor: Atmosphere or NPM

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, npm

I have been installing React into Meteor projects using

```
npm install --save react react-dom
```

What is the difference between doing that and using a package from Atmosphere:

```
meteor add reactjs:react
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a consistency assumption rather a real deal.
You may install react via [bower](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#bower) , [NPM](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html#npm) , Atmosphere or even by cloning the repository.

In my projects, I had clarified dependency management as:

1. Use NPM for backend dependencies ( using Node.js ) or frontend dependencies that require a building / piping / bundling system like Babel, Webpack or Gulp.
2. Use Bower for "presentation" dependencies like Bootstrap, jQuery or prebuilt modules used as is.
3. Use any additional package management tool for any further dependency injection.

**TL;DR**

There are no differences between the two approaches ( although Atmosphere is not mentioned as a proper way to install / build React into the official docs)

If you prefer to keep React rendered in the browser use NPM or Bower. If you need to use React [mapped into Meteor backend's code](https://atmospherejs.com/timbrandin/jsx-templating) as an isomorphic app you may use Atmosphere as it is semantically used as a dependency.